# Select a row of DataGridView based on a string item

Tags: c#, datagridview

Using : **VS2010, .Net 3.5.**
I apologize for my poor Title.

I have a **string item** which, i am sure, is available in a **datagridview**. Now i want to select the row, where the item belongs.

```
            tableName = tmp._Table;     //I have my table_name here
```

//This following code shows what my dgvtablelist have.

```
            dgvTablesList.DataSource = CS.getAllTables(serverName, dbName, authenticationType, logIn, passWord);
```

SO, how would I select my **tableName** in the **DataGridVIew**?

**I dont have any **index**

Answer (score 1):

First find the gridview row index for the searched value:

```
String searchValue = "your_table_name";
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

And then select that..

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index........ This error is catching on if condiotion

Comment: If you only have one column, change Cells[1] to Cells[0]

Comment: yes. I did, and solved. index is found correctly. but ultimately the row is not selected.

Comment: i have solved further. But for 1st time, when i open the app, it's not effected. but in the running program, when i perform this type of action, this is ok then. what could be the problem?

Comment: Your answer did not let me to reach my goal, but it helped me a lot. thanks @StuartDunkeld

Comment: glad to help you,i was busy with my work for which i can't come back to help you with these things..:)

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing this to get the the DataGridView row selected.

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0];
```

Hope this helps.